# How to Display Products in group wise in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to control particular column's(field) space in detail section

See the below Screen I want to reduce blank space between every Product Description

[image]

**Note :-** 1) I grouped fields based on **Marks info**

2) **Packing Info** Column Details Always have 3 lines

**Important** Product Description May be more than 1 Line, See Example below for expected output[image]

FYI:- I have Placed **Marks** & **Packing Info** Filed in Details Section, If I Placed These 2 Fields in Group header section the output will be(Don't want below output)

[image]

**EDIT : 2**

When Adding More Product in one group then the no space found between 2 groups For Example see image below 
[image]

Comment: place Marks and Packing info in Group header and rest in detail section then go to section expert select the group and check the "Underlay following section"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place Marks and Packing info in Group header and rest in detail section then go to section expert select the group and check the "Underlay following section"

Comment: Just Change to "Group header section expert" instead of section expert, because its little bit confusing either Detail section or header section "Section Expert"

Comment: Your Solution Working But Need Some Correction, Please Find Edit 2 in my Question

Comment: Hope this may work...don't suppress the Marks or packing group footer leave it empty space you require between them.

Comment: Its Working When Adding 4 Lines in Product Description, After that Its Merged with Second group- See screenshot https://gyazo.com/45b0eefd1b9602684b269e3369d22f4d

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Edit : 2 - Just Make Some Space in Group Footer Section

Answer (score 0):

This may can help you.

Right Click on the Detail Section and click "Fit Section"